# python printing with os.startfile on windows

Tags: python, printing

I tried to printing an image with

```
os.startfile("pathroimage", "print")
```

It opens windows printing dialog. How can I print iages in background.
Is there another way to do printing with python.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on windows i use win32

Check this: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

or this: http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@c@o@colony_plugins-HEAD@printing@src@printing@win32@system.py

a few days ago I was printing image in this way. the exact size and correctly position was important for me.